# Facebook hovercard jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, facebook

I came across this plugin http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard

However, are there any alternatives which display which of the user's friends have also liked the page?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [Facebook Wall](http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall)? It might be worth a go if Hovercard is not what you're looking for. Perhaps you could, for instance, display the page of whatever you are trying to show "Likes" for.